# Where I can find Lotus Expeditor Toolkit, any version?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lotus-domino, lotus, hcl, hcl-notes

I can't find  Lotus Expeditor Toolkit, when i try download it from IBM site, in last step I have message where writed "can`t find this file on server".
I want this software for create plag-in for Notes Designer.

Comment: You know that IBM sold everything regarding Notes and Domino to HCL some years ago? You need to have a contract with HCL, then you can download the stuff from their site. IBM does not host any downloads for these products anymore

Comment: I am agree with you but, unfortunately support from HCL give me broken link to IBM, where in last step I have message where writed "can`t find this file on server".